# On the Moving Plane Method - Conditions for the reflected cap to stay in the domain

Tags: geometry, partial-differential-equations

In the application of the Moving Plane Method to Poisson's Equation, James Serrin (*A Symmetry Problem in Potential Theory*, 1971) provides the following preliminary construction for the proof:

> Let $T_0$ be a hyperplane not intersecting the (bounded) domain $\Omega$. We suppose this plane to be continuously moved normal to itself to new positions, until ultimatelyit begins to intersect $\Omega$. From that moment onward, at each stage of the motion the resulting plane $T$ will cut off from $\Omega$ a cap $\Sigma(T)$: that is, $\Sigma(T)$ will be that portion of $\Omega$ which lies on the same side of $T$ as the original plane $T_0$. For any cap $\Sigma(T)$ thus formed, we let $\Sigma'(T)$ be its reflection in $T$. Evidently $\Sigma'(T)$ will be contained in $\Omega$ at the beginning of the process; and indeed as $T$ advances into $\Omega$ *the resulting cap $\Sigma'(T)$ will stay within $\Omega$ at least until one of the following two events occur*: ($i$) $\Sigma'(T)$ becomes internally tangent to the boundary of $\Omega$ at some point $P$ not on $T$, or ($ii$) $T$ reaches a position where it is orthogonal to the boundary of $\Omega$ at some point $Q$.

Now, I am having a bit of trouble interpreting these conditions for $\Sigma'(T)$ to leave $\Omega$. I understand condition ($i$). However, **can it happen that $\Sigma'(T)$ leaves $\Omega$ in such a way that only ($ii$) happens?**

I have thought a lot about this. My current understanding is that ($ii$) is not a limit situation for $\Sigma'(T)$ to stay inside $\Omega$, but rather that if ($ii$) occurs, then either $\Sigma'(T)$ is still inside $\Omega$ or ($i$) is occuring as well. I came to think this because this orthogonality is used when it first appears when the plane is moving.

Is my interpretation correct, or is there a positive answer to the question above (boldfaced)?

I tried to be the most clear, but please let me know if it is not sufficient. I will try harder.

Thanks in advance and kindest regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation of the statement is correct and the answer to your bold question is **no**. This is not the goal of the statement in the cited article, anyway.

Let me go into some more detail. The construction of Serrin has the goal to prove $\Omega=\Sigma(T')\cup\Sigma'(T')$, where $T'$ denotes the first position of the hyperplane in which either *(i)* or *(ii)* occurs. In this case, *(ii)* always implies *(i)*, due to easy symmetry considerations. However, in the general setting, *(ii)* can of course occur even if *(i)* doesn't (so if $\Sigma'(T)\subset \Omega$ even if $T$ moves past $T'$), which is what I understand you were asking.